# Hamburger Menu with React JS

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello I am trying to make a hamburger menu bar. But I can't seem to position the circle right icon to the right. When I try to add a padding-right it won't let me.

My JS:

```
{
    SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <div >
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                    <Link to={item.path}>
                        {item.icon}
                        <span>{item.title}</span>
                        <span className={"roundright"}>
                            <PageRight />
                        </span>
                    </Link>

                </li>


            </div>

        );
    })
}
```

My CSS:

```
.nav-text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-text a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;

}

.roundright {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #E7135D;
    font-size: 14px;


    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Here is what I currently have:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Here is my CSS:

Comment: Could you provide a minimal and reproducible example?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a flexbox and the justify-content for this case. You can view more on the space-between property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.php). Note that my answer only contains new classes and not your previously written classes.

Example HTML:

```
<div >
    <Link to={item.path}>
        <li key={index} className={`${item.cName} item-container`}>
            {item.icon}
            <span>{item.title}</span>
            <span className={"roundright"}>
                <PageRight />
            </span>
        </li>
    </Link>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.item-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```